# Microsoft Mdac with SQL Server issue

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008

I am new to Microsoft Mdac => http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/91083/mdac-2-8-for-windows-x64, and I want to use this technology to export data from a SQL Server table (or ADO.Net DataTable object instance) to an Excel file. I am using VS2008 + .Net 2.0 + C# + Windows Server 2008 x64 + SQL Server 2008 Enterprise 64-bit + ADO.Net + ASP.Net + IIS 7.0.

My questions,

1. whether Mdac technology could achieve my goal?
2. any tutorial about this area (export from SQL Server to excel using Mdac) for a newbie with samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you exactly want to export, but here are some good tutorials:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ExportToExcel.aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can only post one link atm, so here another on :) 
http://dotnet-snippets.de/dns/excel-datatable-mittels-oledb-in-excel-dokument-exportieren-SID272.aspx

Comment: Hi YvesR, is there a sample about how to use the function you posted from CodeProject? Thanks.

Comment: What you mean by example? The function there generates a XML Excel flat file. The source is a ADO.NET dataset. The dataset as parameter reference you just create as usual.

Comment: Have you used it in VSTS 2008 + .Net 2.0 + C#? Any issues you find?

Comment: No I didn't but it shouldn't be a problem. I use VS2010 Prof, but there all references available in a quick look. So should work.